# Searching for Variable Scope { } in Text

Tags: java, optimization, pattern-matching, scope

I need to identify {scope} in text, such as source code.
I'm starting with just a single line and will expand to search multiple lines, and exclude comments. I already have working code using Pattern Matcher, but I would like critiquing on how to improve such a search.

```
String line = "{{outside{inside}{inside2}}};";
String scopeOf = "outside";
findscope(line,scopeOf);


private static void findscope(String line,
                              String scopeOf) {

    int layer = 1;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(scopeOf);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        int scopestart = m.start();
        int scopeEnd = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        m.usePattern(Pattern.compile("\\{|\\}"));
        while (m.find()) {
            String group = m.group();
            if (group.equals("{")) {
                layer++;
            } else if (group.equals("}")) {
                layer--;
            }
            if (layer == 0) {
                scopeEnd = m.start();
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Scope of " + scopeOf + " starts at " + scopestart +
        " finishes at " + scopeEnd);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need validation open/close `}{` or only print position open/close?

Comment: Is Java necessary for this? If you are looking to optimize, C or something like that may be more efficient, if it's an option.

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks this example and useage is for java, thank you.

Comment: @MaximShoustin if I understand your question I need validation.

Comment: Then I agree with amit and you cannot just use regex, you will need a parser.

Comment: I think this questions fits better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are using the wrong tool for the job (assuming you are also looking for nested scopes)

Note that regex (in the traditional form of regex) stands for Regular Expression - which is a way to describe a [Regular Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

However, the language `L = { all words with legal scopings }` is irregular - and thus cannot be identified by regex.

This langauge is actually [Conext Free Langauge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language), and can be represented by a [Context Free Grammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).

For parsing:

For relatively simple langauges (scoping is among them) - a deterministic [push-down automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) is enough to verify them.

Some languages require non deterministic push down automaton - which is not very efficiently created, but there is a [dynamic programming algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm) to parse them as well.

---

As a side note, there are some tools such as [JavaCC](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http://javacc.java.net/&ei=Yq1iUubUGqqk4gSY0IDABg&usg=AFQjCNFvozNJ_Rxewupu63AzhtcPSHJu5A&sig2=HCqX8AkfU3h4mGPIXA5adQ&bvm=bv.54934254,d.bGE) that you can use to parse (and generate code/output) - have a look on them, but if you are simply looking for the scoping issue - it is probably an overkill.

---

Edit - pseudo code:

```
curr <- 0
count <- 0 //integer imitates the stack for this simple usage
l <- string.length()
while (curr < l):
   if string.charAt(curr) == '{':
         count++;
   else if string.charAt(curr) == '}':
         if curr <= 0:
              return ERROR;
         count--;
   curr++;
if count != 0:
    return ERROR;
return SUCCESS;
```

Note that in here we can use an integer to imitate the stack, in here an increase is basically a push() and a decrease is a pop().

Comment: He's using the `layers` variable as a counter to simulate a stack in a PDA, so his approach would work just fine, assuming all braces have to be matched (e.g. they can't pop up unmatched in string literals or something).

Comment: @DaoWen don't you agree pushdown automaton will be more efficient, elegant and simple then repeatidly using a regex?

Comment: No, I don't see any real difference. PDAs are just NFAs with a stack added, and since NFAs and regexs are equivalent, adding the stack to the regex should be the exact same thing.

Comment: Okay I've got allot of reading to do, I'll come back once I understanding a tiny bit of JavaCC.

Comment: @AnotherCompilerError Note that only for scoping javaCC is an overkill, but if you want to do more - and actually parse a code, javaCC (or other parsers) is definetly the way you should do it.

Comment: @amit Well in the wider picture this fits within a project I'm making. I have already written the code to ID 'my' supported DataStructures and change them to 'my' swappable DataStructures e.g changing Integer declaration to a String and manipulate the String through txt insertions to behave like the original Integer. all done with regex searches and String replacements.

I wrote the code with the assumption all declarations of Variable names are unique throughout the page, as my code would have no understanding of scope. I now want to add scope.

continued...

Comment: @amit 
Even though I have already built the automation of swapping Data Structures, should I continue down my path or do you believe that JavaCC could aid improve my life with this task? and should abandon my effort and restart?

Comment: @AnotherCompilerError From what I understand - yes. parsing code isn't easy - and generating one is even harder (wait until you efficiently try to implement [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)). Using existing tools will guarantee less bugs and shorter develpoment time.

Comment: @DaoWen Yeah I am aware of the assumption that { or } doesn't appear in String literals or commented code, which will be the next task.

with that in mind would JavaCC be an improved way to go, if it tokens to understand literals and comments then could it save me allot of time in the future or have I come too far to change.

Comment: @amit Do you have much experience with JavaCC, what is the down time to get to grips with it to begin to start making something, useful (All of the above)

Lets assume I'm an Average Masters Student and I'm a little bit above average in my java coding skill.

Comment: @AnotherCompilerError We had a little project, and 2 BSc students developed a simple parser + code generator using javaCC for a java-like langauge within ~40 hours each. Note that most of the work was the code generator. Also, there are existing rules for java that you can modify.

Comment: @AnotherCompilerError - I much prefer [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) to JavaCC. But yes, I'd recommend using a stable parser-generator rather than trying to make an ad-hoc parser yourself.

Comment: I wanted to return to say I'm now using Antlr and it has saved me allot of pain. Thanks guys.